# Excel formula using 'Filename' updating in other worksheets

Tags: excel, date, filenames, title, worksheet

I have my tabs named as month-end dates, and I am constantly forgetting to update the date cell (which becomes important when I have to print).  So I figured I would use the `'Filename'` property, the **Left/Right/Mid function**, and the Date function to automatically set the date cell.  This is what I came up with:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(RIGHT(CELL("filename"),8),4),LEFT(RIGHT(CELL("filename"),8),2),MID(RIGHT(CELL("filename"),8),3,2))
```

The internal "**RIGHT**" grabs the last 8 chars of the filename (the worksheet title), then the external substring functions portion it out so that it can be used as parameters for the "**DATE**" function.  And this works fine.  The problem comes when I try to copy this over from worksheet to worksheet.

First, I have made sure that my tabs are NOT grouped.

But still, whenever I calculate ONE of the cells containing the filename property, it updates ALL of the worksheets to have the date of the last sheet used to calculate.

**I.E.** I calculate the date cell in sheet **"05312013"** and it changes all months' date cell to **"05/31/2013"** instead of JUST that one sheet as intended.

What is happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make CELL function always refer to the worksheet in which the formula resides you need to use a **cell reference** in each `CELL` function (any cell reference, but A1 is the default option), i.e.

`=DATE(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),4),LEFT(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),8),2),MID(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),8),3,2))`

If you don't do that then it refers to the last worksheet **changed** - which clearly isn't what you want